# Multiplying two arrays in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to multiply two multidimensional arrays to form a matrix. I have this function. This should work in theory. However, I am just getting 0s and large/awkward numbers. Can someone help me with this?

```
int **matrix_mult( int **a, int **b, int nr1, int nc1, int nc2 )
{
    int **c;
    int i,j,k,l;
    c = malloc(sizeof(int *)*nr1);

    if (c == NULL){
        printf("Insuff memm");
    }

    for(l=0;l<nr1;l++){
        c[l] = malloc(sizeof(int)*nc1);
        if (c[l] == NULL){
            printf("Insuff memm");
        }

    }//for loop


    for (i=0;i<nr1;i++){
        for (j=0;j<nc2;j++){
            for (k=0;k<nc1;k++){

                c[i][j] = (a[i][k]) * (b[k][j]);
    }
    }
    }
        return( c );  
    }
```

Comment: a minimal example with a main() and some sample matrices would be handy

Comment: Not really related to your question, but instead of just printf'ing "Insuff mem" when malloc fails, you should at least stop doing anything with the unallocated space.

Comment: @user373466, I've spent more time on this than I should have. A vote or two and an accept would be appreciated.

Comment: When the code is obviously broken *"This should work in theory."* is a bold claim!  Are you saying your code is right and the compiler is broken!?  Not the most likely explanation in any event.

Answer (score 2):

Are you doing mathematical matrix multiplication? If so shouldn't it be:

```
for(i = 0; i < nr1; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < nc1; j++)
    {
        c[i][k] = 0;

        for(k = 0; k < nc2; k++)
        {
            c[i][k] += (a[i][j]) * (b[j][k]);
        }
    }
}
```

My full and final solution, tested to produce sensible results (I didn't actually do all the calculations myself manually to check them) and without any sensible niceties such as checking memory allocations work, is:

```
int **matrix_mult(int **a, int **b, int nr1, int nc1, int nc2)
{
    int **c;
    int i, j, k;

    c = malloc(sizeof(int *) * nr1);

    for (i = 0; i < nr1; i++)
    {
        c[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * nc2);

        for (k = 0; k < nc2; k++)
        {
            c[i][k] = 0;

            for (j = 0; j < nc1; j++)
            {
                c[i][k] += (a[i][j]) * (b[j][k]);
            }
        }
    }

    return c;
}
```

There were a few typos in the core of the for loop in my original answer, mostly due to my being mislead by a different answer. These have been corrected for posterity.

Comment: Good guess, but it didn't solve the problem. I am noticing that **a and **b are NULL. I tried to malloc them, like i did with **c, but it's not seem to be working

Comment: Err you mean `**a == NULL`? NULL = 0 so all that means is that `a[0][0] == 0`. So what if the top left element of the array is zero? If `a == NULL` then you should get a segmentation fault.

Comment: Well, when I put this snippet inside my 3rd for loop.
if (a[i][k] == 0){
        printf("*A* NULL\n");

} It get printed.

Comment: Does your first array have any zero elements? I'd be surprised if it didn't!

Comment: I just updated the c += a * b line as it was wrong. I copied from Buddhabrot and he's got it wrong.

Comment: Why do you use `l` and not `i` when allocating memory for `c`? In any case you need to malloc `nc2` elements, not `nc1`. Your code looks fine apart from the fact you don't initialise `c[i][j]` to zero and you use `=` instead of `+=`.

Comment: Someone downvoted this answer! I spent ages on this and produced working and TESTED code, so why would anyone downvote it?

Answer (score 0):

If you change `c[i][j] = (a[i][k]) * (b[k][j]);` to `c[i][j] += (a[i][k]) * (b[k][j]);` in your code then it will work just fine provided that

- nr1 is number of rows of matrix a
- nc1 is the number of columns of the matrix a
- nc2 is the number of columns of the matrix b

Just be sure that the matrix c is initiated with zeroes. You can just use calloc instead of malloc when allocating space, or memset the allocated array after a call to malloc.

One more tip is to avoid using the letter `l` when accessing array elements. when tired, you will have hard time noticing errors with `l` vs `1`.